# How can I get neovim to load my init.vim file when in sudo mode?

Tags: permissions, sudo, vim

I'm having an issue with Neovim on a Raspberry Pi coding with Python.

I have installed it by sudo apt-get install Neovim, and it works using just the `nvim` command on the command line.
For some reason, I can create a file with `nvim filename.py`, but it will end as a read-only file.

If I run Neovim as `sudo nvim` instead, I can write to the file, but my `init.vim` file is not being loaded.

I have created my `init.vim` here: `/home/pi/.config/nvim/init.vim`

Does it have to be placed elsewhere, or can I make some kind of link to it?

I have also tried giving `filename.py` writing permission with
`sudo chmod a+w filename.py`, but that leads me to an error code "E509" when trying to save by `:wq`.  It will save with `:wq!` though.

Comment: I am not familiar with NeoVim (I just use vim), It sounds like you start in Read Only mode. Once you opened your file in vim, could you try: `:set noro`? That should disable read only mode. If that works, you are setting `ro` somewhere in your init.vim.

Comment: I am not sure how init.vim is located, I assume it uses $HOME. Could you show me the output of this command? `sudo env | grep HOME`

Comment: It's unclear how editing a file with `nvim filename.py` cause the file to be read-only, unless you mean you can't save the file due to permissions on the current directory.

Answer (score 7):

You should use `sudoedit` or `sudo -e` instead of `sudo nvim`. You can choose your editor by setting the `SUDO_EDITOR`, `VISUAL`, or `EDITOR` environment variable.

When using `sudoedit` or `sudo -e`, a copy of the given file is edited as the user invoking the command, which means that the initialisation files associated with the editor (`~/.config/nvim/init.vim` in the case of Neovim) will be read from that user's account, not from the root user's account.

Answer (score 2):

For those who don't have a `sudoedit` command. We can just make an alias using sudo :)

```
export SUDO_EDITOR="nvim"
alias "sudoedit"='function _sudoedit(){sudo -e "$1";};_sudoedit'
```

Now doing something like `sudoedit foo` will run `sudo -e foo`, and use `nvim` as the editor, with all your plugins and configurations.

Comment: I needed to add a space between the curly bracket and sudo ( { sudo ) for it to work in bash.

Answer (score -1):

To do what you would like to do you should copy your init.vim or .vimrc file to `/root/.config/nvim`.

You should also remove the plugin section because it will cause problems when in root.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem, when I use sudo, I lost the neovim configuration, this worked for me:

`sudo -Es nvim README.md`